# How to create a floating horizontal scroll bar in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, scrollbar

I have an advanced data grid with many rows and columns. When I want to got to last column in the grid I have to move at the bottom of the page for horizontal scrolling. I think a floating horizontal bar may solve this issue. Is anyone know how to create a **floating scroll bar** in **flex.**

Comment: A DataGrid's horizontal scrollbar is always visible; you shouldn't have to scroll down. There's probably somethin wrong with your layout: show some code so we can help.

Comment: Yes its always visible. In my case i have more than 3000+ rows in AdvDatagrid. So I need to go that much down for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: **One thing also I want to mention. I am integrating flex with .net. In my site I have a left page and a main page. The left page of my site is 25% occupied in the screen and rest by the main page. In this main page i am using the flex mxml file. I want to make the horizontal scroll of this mxml to float.**

Comment: I think you got me wrong: you're not supposed to scroll down to be able to scroll horizontally. The Horizontal scrollbar should be always visible _on screen_.

Comment: You are right. Its always visible. I think i have explained it wrongly. In  my case I have an aspx page which uses a flex mxml page in it. I want to scroll down the aspx page to access the mxml horizontal scroll bar.